# SOLR 6.3.0 - Date Range not returning any results

Tags: solr

I have the query below that should return a subset of documents but it returns all documents and I am at a loss to understand why.

```
select q=*:*&
facet=true&
facet.range=date&
f.date.facet.range.start=2017-02-07T00:00:00Z&
f.date.facet.range.end=2017-02-08T00:00:00Z&
f.date.facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
```

the managed-schema.xml:

```
<field name="date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q is the part where you ask what docs you want to work with. Now it returns all docs cause you are asking for all docs (q= * : * without the spaces). If you want a subset of docs there (based on a date) you have to add fq to filter out docs you dont want, so:

```
 select q=*:*&fq=date:[2017-02-07T00:00:00Z TO 2017-02-08T00:00:00Z]
```

Now, once you get that subset of the docs, you can ask for additional info on that subset, like faceting. So you add all your additional facet params on top to get that info:

```
select q=*:*&
fq=date:[2017-02-07T00:00:00Z TO 2017-02-08T00:00:00Z]&
facet=true&
facet.range=date& 
f.date.facet.range.start=2017-02-07T00:00:00Z&
f.date.facet.range.end=2017-02-08T00:00:00Z&
f.date.facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
```